# Is this incredible microscope technology real?

Tags: optics, particle-physics, atomic-physics, microscopy, technology

I recall reading about the relatively old invention of a microscope-like device; apparently able to zoom much further (and with greater clarity) than more "advanced" modern technology.

I don't recall the name of the device or who invented it. I don't actually know much about it at all. All I have are a couple of incredible black and white images which, I'm told, were published in an old (1950's or 1960's; I think..) *issue of **National Geographic** magazine.*

Is this technology *real?*
Or was it some kind of *hoax?*
If it *is* real, why don't we use it *today?*

Any additional information is welcome and much appreciated. Thank you.

---

***Science and Mechanics*** *(January 1964) ~*
***"First Photos of the Atom!"***  *by David Legerman*
[image: Remarkable image of an Iron atom]

***Extraordinary Science*** *(Jan/Feb/Mar 1991) ~*
***"Applications of Scalar Technology: The Liatronics Microscope"*** *By Dr Henry C. Monteith*
[image: Remarkable sub-atomic photography]

---

I'm not sure if the following images are actually related; but I found them bundled together with the first two. I have included them just in case.

---

[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: The first is probably due to some electron microscope, see the history and disadvantages etc. and physics at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_microscope - the colorful pictures are computer plots of well-known functions.

Comment: Whatever the first picture is of, it isn't atoms.

Comment: A National Geographic search doesn't return anything with that text. There would have been no instrument at that time that would have returned atomic images at the orbital level and if it had existed, it wouldn't have looked like the image shown above.

Comment: A Google image search leads to this: http://rexresearch.com/nemes/1nemes.htm. The patents mentioned in that article are real and they are full of nonsense. Whether the "inventor" was trying to actually defraud someone is, of course, unknown without a look at old police/legal files.

Comment: NYT article about the invention: http://www.nytimes.com/1964/04/18/cartoonist-wins-patent-for-heating-pad.html

Comment: Another article about the man: http://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=DS19531015.2.113... this time  "perfecting an antibiotic for tropical sicknesses"... hmmm... the man was either a real genius (similar to Buckaroo Banzai) or he was a fraud, after all.  :-)

Comment: Want to visit his grave? http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=68133615... I am amazed how much stuff is on the internet these days. :-) The microscope technology is still being developed...err... continuously "refined". It was obviously not good enough in the 1960s, yet, and needed 50 years more research funding from people like you. It will become available any day now... :-)

Comment: The first image, although it seems to be being used misleadingly to back highly dubious claims, does look vaguely like a field ion micrograph, which *is* a genuine technique from about that era. These indeed were used to visualize the atomic lattice of a sample, which needed to be made into a very sharp needle. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_ion_microscope). Why don't we still use them? Modern electron microscopes are way better. But a field ion microscope still makes a pretty cool home project, if you're a handy experimentalist.

Comment: @tfb FYI: It is allegedly *sub-atomic* iron.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance *"Modern electron microscope are way better."* I've never seen electron microscopy produce an image as amazing as this. Have you?

Comment: @tjt263 I meant relative to the 1960s field ion microscopes. we can't produce images like that, but we can learn a great deal more than we could with the early FIM

Comment: This question is off-topic here, but looks like a good fit for [Skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm not interested in that demographics opinion, to be honest. I'm interested in the opinions of physicists. I'm not trying to create some nonsense, pseudo-science, crackpot hype. I am looking for serious answers, firmly rooted in logic and understanding.

Comment: @tjt263 In that case, phrase your question appropriately for the demographic you want to take your question seriously, including the use of (what's essentially) clickbait in titles.

Comment: If you have a problem, try doing something constructive, like suggesting an edit, instead of whinging about it, Pisant.

Answer (score 5):

Hoax. Let's read the caption of the picture:

> Note "energy lines" extending from atoms' nuclei

...energy lines? Does that sound serious to you?

Ok, let's do an internet search (Elmer Nemes microscope). The first result is this [page](http://rexresearch.com/nemes/1nemes.htm).

> The inventor of the Nemescope was a brilliant brain surgeon. His name was Elmer P. Nemes and he ran the Nemes Research Laboratories, 4207 West Third Street, Los Angeles, California during the middle 1950's.

Brain surgeon? Must have had a really good formation in experimental physics too.

> His invention, the Nemescope, which we are detailing on these pages in an effort to entice others to recreate this vitally important work, was stolen from a store called the Bryn Camera Shop on Melrose Avenue in 1957, ending a remarkable series of experiments and demonstrations. The device was in the shop to have an electric field finder installed.

Stolen? Sounds fishy. But let's take a look at the  of the website...

[image: homepage]

Aether? Alchemy? Anti-G? Well, sure we can trust these guys!

Notice: no trace of the Nemescope or of Elmer Nemes in serious websites.

If you are interested in *actual* image of atomic structure, you could read [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0503671.pdf). This is how real atomic resolution looks like:[image]

And this was obtained in 2000 using an AFM. Seems rather impossible that an even better technology was available in 1964.

Comment: No. "Energy-lines" sounds ridiculous. But then again, I've never been inside an atom, or seen one up close enough to inspect it, so who knows? Atoms are held together by electromagnetism, right? I wouldn't be surprised if there was some kind of arc bridging the gap. But I don't know. That's why I'm interested. *"Seems rather impossible that an even better technology was available in 1964."* Well, yes. It would certainly be quite remarkable if that were the case.

Comment: The fact that there is no trace of this technology in any serious archive (for example arxiv.org) is for me the proof that this is a hoax. Also, those pictures are really interesting (I wonder how they were made) but look nothing like atomic orbitals.

Comment: Is the ***New York Times*** considered a reputable source?

Comment: Did this come up in the NYT too? Anyway, the NYT is not a scientific publication.

Comment: @tjt263 Every single working scientist I know who has been interviewed by a science writer for a mainstream publication has a story about some horrible misquote or mis-characterization in what made press. Even articles in science-focused, popular publications generally have some problems, though they are no usually as bad. It's so ubiquitous that you come to expect it. The fact that the Times is reputable doesn't imply that everything you read in there about cutting edge science or technology should be taken at face value.

Comment: I really don't care about any of that. I just want to look inside atoms and molecules.